# I am trying to make my own version of vector's swap in C++03 and am completely stuck/baffled by error

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a swap method in my version of a vector class that uses C++03 format without boost. My code I have currently is

```
template <class T>
void kvector<T>::swap(kvector<T> &in)
{
    kvector<T>* temp = &in; //copying the pointer of in into temp and therefore bypassing the assignment operator
    //now switch in and this and than this and temp using pointer arithmetic to again bypass the assignment operator
    //!note: the pointer based arithmetic used in this swap method is exponentially faster than using an
    //!assignment operator or copy constructor

    &in = this;
    this = temp;
    //!no need to set the data pointer of temp to 0 since temp is a pointer and will not get
    //!deleted automatically. Since both in and this still exist at the end of this method
    //!than no memory can leak from this method
}
```

which attempts to pass around the vectors as pointers. I am getting an error from `&in = this;` and `this = temp;`. The error is expression is 'not assignable'. I just don't understand what this error means and why this is an error. Can someone please explain this? I am baffled.

Comment: Normally, you would swap the member variables of `kvector<T>`. Why don't you do that? Additionally, you can't change what a reference points to, which is what you try to do on the second line. And you also can't change what `this` points to, which is what you try to do on the third line.

Comment: You can't assign something to the address of an object. It stays where it is in memory.

Comment: Oh so that's what is going on. Okay that makes sense. Should I make a temporary copy of the vector in and than swap the member variables instead?

Comment: Why are you restricting your vrrsion of `swap` to vectors? If it works, it should work for every type. Ih fact it is so universal, one would expect it to be built into the language. You want to ask yourself wjy this is not the case.

Comment: "Should I make a temporary copy of the vector". If you want to completely defeat the purpose of `swap`, which is *avoiding copies*, then go ahead.

Comment: the temporary copy is only making a shallow copy. It would be very fast and would do almost the exact same thing as me making temporary variables. The only difference is the extra cost of construction and deletion.

Comment: I ended up using std::swap() for all of the classes members not sure how fast that is but it works.

Comment: Thanks n.m. for the help. From your comments I ended up piecing together a working solution. Can you post your comments as a solution so I can give you credit.